# Android, Gradle: How to deploy library on the Nexus repository as per build variant?

Tags: android, gradle, deployment, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an Android library.

I have a Nexus repository, so I can upload the ".aar" file on the server.

To deploy automatically, I wrote some code in the gradle file like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 10006
        versionName "1.00.06"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            defaultConfig.versionName = defaultConfig.versionName + "-SNAPSHOT"
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            pom.project {
                artifactId 'mylib'
                group = 'com.my.lib'
                project.group = 'com.my.lib'
                version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            }

            repository(url: 'MY_URL.com') {
                authentication(userName: USER_NAME, password: _PASSWORD)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'My_URL2.com') {
                authentication(userName: USER_NAME, password: NEXUS_PASSWORD)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I change the build variant to "release", it is deployed with version name + "-SNAPSHOT".

I want to remove the suffix in case of "release".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be resolved by either updating the upload code as shown in this blog: https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/

Or you need to clean build your project first and then upload the artifacts

Comment: I am not saying you to change to Artifactory server. The same thing can be implemented with Nexus

Comment: I've looked at the link, but I'm not sure how the version name differs according to the build variant.